# undefined method `read' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Why am I getting undefined method `read' for nil:NilClass when I am trying to email an uploaded attachment?

listings_controller.rb

```
def send_resume_email
  @listing = Listing.find(params[:id])
  @user = User.find_by_id(params[:id])
  UserMailer.new_resume(params[:resume].read(), params[:resume].original_filename, @user, @listing).deliver
  redirect_to findjobs_path, notice: 'Message sent'
end
```

user_mailer.rb

```
def new_resume(user, listing, file, filename)
  @listing = listing
  @user = user
  attachments[filename] = file
  @url = 'http://www.new.com'
  mail(to: listing.user.email, subject: 'Thanks for the awesome site')
end
```

I really appreciate your help.

Comment: `params[:resume]` is nil.  How are you passing it to the controller?

Comment: As an aside, the order of the arguments you are passing to `new_resume` don't match the method definition..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several issues with your code.

First, you are trying to find two resources using the same `id` param. The `params[:id]` should belong to either the user or the listing. Which one is it?

On another note, `User.find_by_id(params[:id])` is redundant. `User.find(params[:id])` should suffice, since the default lookup value for [`find`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/find/class) is `id`.

```
  @listing = Listing.find(params[:id])
  @user = User.find_by_id(params[:id])
```

Finally, you are calling the method `read()` on a params hash.

```
UserMailer.new_resume(params[:resume].read(), params[:resume].original_filename, @user, @listing).deliver
```

Where is the hash coming from? And how does `params[:resume]` have an instantiated object that you can call `read()` on? Usually param hashes are a result of form submissions or a browser request, so it is unlikely to contain an instantiated object that you can call methods on.

And this is the source of your error. The error tells you that `params[:resume]` is `nil`. Therefore calling any method on it will raise an error.

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation and the time you put into this. I looked at this problem from a wrong angle.

Answer (score 0):

The error is just what it says:

```
 params[:resume].nil?
```

would evaluate to true, and of course, nil:NilClass has no method read.

You can check that your parameter is being populated by

```
 unless params[:resume].blank?
    r = params[:resume].read
 end
```